# PHP: How to transport vars from php cmd (executing from shell) to PHP GET and POST Array?

Tags: shell, post, get, php

i have some scripts that need GET and POST values to start, and i wanna test them over shell.
Is there some way to pass the values to that arrays to avoid using `getenv()` function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you elaborate your question a little more please.

Comment: It's worth noting that HTTP and command line differ in more than GET and POST. In your case, it may be relevant or not, but you should take it into account.

Comment: The best answer to my question was from `cletus`, and the best solution was from `umop`! +1 for both and Correct Answer  for `umop`.
Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your main goal is just to test from the command line, I would use the [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) command and just call your script with the query string (for GET) and pass post data using the `--post-data=string` parameter of wget (for POST).

If your goal is to not use a webserver at all for testing for some reason, I'd recommend using a wrapper and encapsulating your access to GET and POST data so that you can test it either way.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a wrapper script that sets the relevant globals and environment variables and then calls your script.

Comment: The best answer to my question was from `cletus`, and the best solution was from `umop`! +1 for both and Correct Answer  for `umop`.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli' && empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){ // make sure we're running in CLI
    $args = $argv; // copy the argv array, we want to keep the original for (possible) future uses
    array_shift($args); // the $argv[0] is the filename, we don't need it
    for($i = 0;$i < ($argc - 1);$i++){
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $args[$i]);
        $_REQUEST[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Of course, more features can be added by using getopts (like, --get abc=def ghi=jkl --post name=test passwd=test --cookie ilike=cookie) but that's up to you.

Comment: +1 for the code...

didn't understood the last part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli')
{
    associateGetPost();
}

function associateGetPost()
{
    $_GET = $_POST = array(); //Reset
    foreach($args as $id => $value)
    {
        if(substr($value,0,5) == '--get')
        {
            $_GET = parse_str(substr($value,5,-1))
        }elseif(substr($value,0,6) == '--post')
        {
            $_GET = parse_str(substr($value,6,-1))
        }
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: +1, but will use `umop` answer. Thanks for the Help `RobertPitt`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: `Note: When running on the command line , this will not include the argv and argc entries; these are present in the $_SERVER  array . `

thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

In command line you call as

```
php test.php something1 something2 something3
```

and your test.php is

```
<?php
print_r($argv);
?>
```

and output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => something1
    [2] => something2
    [3] => something3
)
```